# javascript alert output is cut and replaced with dots

Tags: javascript, json, string, alert

I have a string (`exportString`) created with `JSON.stringify(anArrayOfObjects)`. I use this string to export the objects, and later import them and create them again. So the `exportString` is pretty large.

For export, I use `console.log(exportString)` and `alert(exportString)` (for copy-paste export-import... pretty naive, but it works).

Now here is my problem:
The output of the console is correct. I can copy it, and later paste it for import and everything is fine.
But the output of the alert is sometimes wrong. In the middle of the string, some characters (~220) are just left out and replaced by `...`.

It does not happen everytime, but sometimes it does, so it is not reliable. In this case I encountered the following replacement (excerpt):
This:

```
,"z":0.6088229153281304},"heading":8.881784197001252e-16,"pitch":-1.5707953492060365,"roll":0},"frustumFov":1.0471975511965976,"frustumNear":1,"frustumFar":500000000},"thingy-greatStuffUnicornRainbow-testSpeed-index-3":{"easingFunction":"LINEAR_NONE",
```

was shortened to:

```
,"z":0.60...:"LINEAR_NONE",
```

I guess I just should not use alert in this way, and instead use the alert to say "look into the console output".

But I am very curious: Why is the output replaced by three dots, in the middle of the string?
Neverthe less, the scroll bar appears, so the length shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: which browser you're using?

Comment: what happens when you try this: alert `(JSON.stringify(anArrayOfObjects))`

Comment: @KhairulIslam I use Chrome.

Comment: @JordanHendrix Same thing. This was actually the first version, later I put the string into the variable `exportString` to have a better comparison between alert output and console output.